# FileNotFoundError when users try to upload a photo

Tags: python, django

I receive `FileNotFoundError` error messages when users try to sign up to my website and upload a photo. The error messages are like:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/<file_name>.upload.jpg'
```

Where `<file_name>` is a random file name.

I received a few messages like this recently and these users were not able to upload a photo and complete the registration (a user must have a profile photo to become an active member on Speedy Match). Do you know what is the problem? I'm using Django 2.1.15 with Python 3.6.8.

I checked now with Chrome and Firefox and I was able to sign up to my website and upload photos. Most of the users who signed up to the website uploaded a photo successfully. But it failed for some specific users recently.

Here is some code:

```
def clean_photo(self):
    photo = self.files.get('photo')
    if (photo):
        speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_photo_for_user(user=self.instance.user, photo=photo)
    else:
        photo = self.instance.user.photo
        speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_photo_for_user(user=self.instance.user, photo=photo, test_new_photo=False)
    return self.cleaned_data

def save(self, commit=True):
    if (commit):
        if ('photo' in self.fields):
            if (self.files):
                user_image = Image(owner=self.instance.user, file=self.files['photo'])
                user_image.save()
                self.instance.user.photo = user_image
        for field_name in self.user_fields:
            if (field_name in self.fields):
                setattr(self.instance.user, field_name, self.cleaned_data[field_name])
        self.instance.user.save()
    super().save(commit=commit)

def validate_photo_for_user(user, photo, test_new_photo=True):
    validate_photo(photo=photo)
    if (test_new_photo):
        user._photo = user.photo
    photo_is_valid = False
    try:
        if (test_new_photo):
            user_image = Image(owner=user, file=photo)
            user_image.save()
            user.photo = user_image
        profile_picture_html = render_to_string(template_name="accounts/tests/profile_picture_test.html", context={"user": user})
        logger.debug('validate_photo_for_user::user={user}, profile_picture_html={profile_picture_html}'.format(
            user=user,
            profile_picture_html=profile_picture_html,
        ))
        if (not ('speedy-core/images/user.svg' in profile_picture_html)):
            photo_is_valid = True
    except:
        photo_is_valid = False
    if (test_new_photo):
        user.photo = user._photo
        try:
            user_image.delete()
        except:
            pass
    if (not (photo_is_valid)):
        raise ValidationError(_("You can't use this format for your profile picture. Only JPEG or PNG formats are accepted."))
```

The code of the websites can be seen on [GitHub](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net).

Here are the details I received by email:

```
FileNotFoundError at /registration-step-2/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/....upload.jpg' (I removed the file name)
Request Method: POST
Request URL: https://he.speedymatch.com/registration-step-2/
Django Version: 2.1.15
Exception Type: FileNotFoundError
Exception Value:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/....upload.jpg' (I removed the file name)
Exception Location: .../site-packages/django/core/files/move.py in file_move_safe, line 56 (I removed the path)
Python Executable: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Python Version: 3.6.8
```

I also received a backtrace with lots of variables but it's too personal to share on this website.

The backtrace contains the following lines:

```
self.object = form.save()

user_image.save()

return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)

self._save_parents(cls, using, update_fields)

self._save_table(cls=parent, using=using, update_fields=update_fields)

for f in non_pks]

for f in non_pks]

file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)

self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)

return self._save(name, content)

file_move_safe(content.temporary_file_path(), full_path)

with open(old_file_name, 'rb') as old_file:
```

Comment: @Uri Are you able to reproduce with file size more than 2.5 MB?

Comment: @aaron Yes! I tested both our staging and production servers and uploaded images of 7.3 MB and they both failed with the same error message. How do I prevent this error and either resize the image (which is better) or display a friendly error message to the user?

Comment: I would try out @aaron's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in settings fixes the problem, at least temporarily:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = int(15 * 1024 * 1024)  # 15 MB
```

`user_image.save()` is called twice - once to validate the picture and then once again to save it as the user's profile picture, if it's valid. This causes an error if the file size is more than `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` bytes, which defaults to 2.5 MB. Calling `user_image.save()` once will solve the problem.

I fixed the code, here is the code that works. Each file is saved only once:

```
def clean_photo(self):
    photo = self.files.get('photo')
    if (photo):
        user_image = Image(owner=self.instance.user, file=photo)
        user_image.save()
        self.instance.user._new_photo = user_image
        speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_photo_for_user(user=self.instance.user, photo=photo, test_new_photo=True)
    else:
        photo = self.instance.user.photo
        speedy_match_accounts_validators.validate_photo_for_user(user=self.instance.user, photo=photo, test_new_photo=False)
    return self.cleaned_data

def save(self, commit=True):
    if (commit):
        if ('photo' in self.fields):
            photo = self.files.get('photo')
            if (photo):
                self.instance.user.photo = self.instance.user._new_photo
        for field_name in self.user_fields:
            if (field_name in self.fields):
                setattr(self.instance.user, field_name, self.cleaned_data[field_name])
        self.instance.user.save()
    super().save(commit=commit)

def validate_photo_for_user(user, photo, test_new_photo):
    validate_photo(photo=photo)
    if (test_new_photo):
        user._photo = user.photo
    photo_is_valid = False
    try:
        if (test_new_photo):
            user.photo = user._new_photo
        profile_picture_html = render_to_string(template_name="accounts/tests/profile_picture_test.html", context={"user": user})
        logger.debug('validate_photo_for_user::user={user}, profile_picture_html={profile_picture_html}'.format(
            user=user,
            profile_picture_html=profile_picture_html,
        ))
        if (not ('speedy-core/images/user.svg' in profile_picture_html)):
            photo_is_valid = True
    except:
        photo_is_valid = False
    if (test_new_photo):
        user.photo = user._photo
    if (not (photo_is_valid)):
        raise ValidationError(_("You can't use this format for your profile picture. Only JPEG or PNG formats are accepted."))
```

With this code I can keep `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` as the default (2.5 MB) or any value. Currently I set it to 7.5 MB.

Answer (score 4):

The error is only reproducible if the file size is larger than 2.5 MB:

```py
# Maximum size, in bytes, of a request before it will be streamed to the
# file system instead of into memory.
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440  # i.e. 2.5 MB
```

To prevent the error, you can do one of these:

- Check the filesystem user's permission for the `/tmp` directory and grant access if possible.
- Set `FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR` to a directory in which the filesystem user is able to write and read. This should be cleared periodically in case Python's `NamedTemporaryFile` is unable to unlink.